# Сложить значения в строке

Tags: mysql

Привет всем.

Есть простая таблица "дата - значение 1 - значение 2 - значение 3 ... значение N".
Требуется сложить все значения в строке.

Пробую:

```
select SUM(`e_01_00` and `e_02_00` and `e_03_00` and `e_04_00` and `e_05_00` and `e_06_00`) from elect where elect_date = '2015-02-01';
```

Выход после запроса 1. Но это неверно. Так как сколько бы значений ни ставил, все равно 1. Пробовал запятые вместо and - выдает ошибку. Все значения float (0.3, 0.9, 0.6 и так далее).

Кто подскажет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй:

```
select
    SUM(`e_01_00`) +
    SUM(`e_02_00`) +
    SUM(`e_03_00`) +
    SUM(`e_04_00`) +
    SUM(`e_05_00`) +
    SUM(`e_06_00`)
from elect
where elect_date = '2015-02-01';
```

Или

```
select SUM(
    `e_01_00` +
    `e_02_00` +
    `e_03_00` +
    `e_04_00` +
    `e_05_00` +
    `e_06_00`)
from elect
where elect_date = '2015-02-01';
```

Comment: Заработало! 
Спасибо!
Я еще пару вариантов перебрал - НО этот самый шустрый!!

Блин, все же очевидно, сам не вставил + между колонками ((((из которых выбирал значения...